# dplyr: How to calculate frequency of different values within each group

Tags: r, dplyr, frequency

I am probably having a failry easy question but cannnot figure it out.

I am having a dataset that has two variables, both factors. It looks like this:

```
my.data<-data.frame(name=c("a","a","b","b","b","b", "b", "b", "e", "e", "e"),
                var1=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 4, 1, 3, 4, 3))
```

I would like to calculate the frequency of 1,2,3 and 4 for all a, b and e aggregated later into one row. That means that all "a", "b" and "e" should be in one row and then I would like to create 4 variables which will indicate the frequency of all 1,2,3 and 4 across these rows. I have managed to calculate the frequencies for all counts of "a", "b" and "e" but I can't collapse all the "a", "b" and "e" into seperate rows.

My code is this one:

```
a <- my.data %>%
dplyr:: select(name, var1) %>%
mutate(name = as.factor(name),
     var1 = as.factor(var1)) %>% 
group_by(name, var1) %>%
summarise(n = n()) %>%
mutate(freq = n / sum(n))
```

My results should look like this:

```
name   Freq1   Freq2   Freq3   Freq4
  a    0,00    0,00    0,5     0,5
  b    0,30    0,30    0,30    0,10
  e    0,20    0,20    0,20    0,40
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can also make use of package `janitor` to great advantage here:

```
library(janitor)

my.data %>%
  tabyl(name, var1) %>%
  adorn_percentages()

 name         1         2         3         4
    a 0.5000000 0.5000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
    b 0.3333333 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.3333333
    e 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.6666667 0.3333333
```

---

OR

```
my.data %>%
  tabyl(name, var1) %>%
  adorn_percentages() %>%
  adorn_totals(c('row', 'col')) %>%
  adorn_pct_formatting(2)

  name      1      2      3      4   Total
     a 50.00% 50.00%  0.00%  0.00% 100.00%
     b 33.33% 16.67% 16.67% 33.33% 100.00%
     e  0.00%  0.00% 66.67% 33.33% 100.00%
 Total 83.33% 66.67% 83.33% 66.67% 300.00%
```

Comment: Looks much nicer this way my friend, Thank you.

Comment: janitor my fav package for summary/cross-tabulation

Comment: Hey, that worked wonders. Thank you very much for your answer. I appreciate :)

Answer (score 3):

You could also use base R's

```
prop.table(table(my.data), 1)
```

returning

```
    var1
name         1         2         3         4
   a 0.5000000 0.5000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
   b 0.3333333 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.3333333
   e 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.6666667 0.3333333
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pivot_wider` to bring the data in wide format -

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

my.data %>%
  count(name, var1) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(n = prop.table(n)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = var1, values_from = n, names_prefix = 'Freq')

#  name   Freq1  Freq2  Freq3  Freq4
#  <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 a      0.5    0.5   NA     NA    
#2 b      0.333  0.167  0.167  0.333
#3 e     NA     NA      0.667  0.333
```

Comment: Hi Ronak, thank you very much. Although it works on these data. It doesn't work on the ones that I have. I get the following error: Warning message:
Values are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.
* Use `values_fn = list` to suppress this warning.
* Use `values_fn = length` to identify where the duplicates arise
* Use `values_fn = {summary_fun}` to summarise duplicates

Comment: Hmmm...that's weird and should not happen. Can you try replacing `count` with `dplyr::count` and see if anything changes?

Comment: Hi, I already have that in the beginning of my code. I apply a filter before all of those operations.

Comment: Yes, but `count` is part of `plyr` library as well and I feel it might be accidentally masking `count` from `dplyr`. Hence, I asked to use `dplyr::count` instead of only `count`. If that doesn't help you can use `pivot_wider(names_from = var1, values_from = n, names_prefix = 'Freq', values_fn = sum)` to sum the values for each combination.

Comment: I am not supposed to have them as factors I guess

Answer (score 0):

```
library(purrr)
my.data %>% 
  split(.$name) %>% 
  {cbind(name = names(.), map_dfr(., ~pluck(.x, "var1") %>% table() %>% prop.table()))}

  name         1         2         3         4
1    a 0.5000000 0.5000000        NA        NA
2    b 0.3333333 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.3333333
3    e        NA        NA 0.6666667 0.3333333
```